# Is there a way to see gifts you've sent on Steam?

Tags: steam

I remember there being a button to view a list of all the guest passes and gifts you've sent to people on Steam, but it seems to have disappeared after the Steam inventory update.

Is it still there, in a different place, or was it removed completely?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is absolutely a way to see who you have sent gifts to in the past:

1. Click **View** > **Inventory**
2. Then click **Games** > **Manage Gifts and Guest Passes**. This circumvents a user interface bug that often does not show the next dialogue.
3. Click **Pending Gifts**
4. Click **View Gift History**

[image]

Voila! You should be met with a screen that looks a little something like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to go via pending gifts - below that link, there's a line, and on the far right, there's a link to the history.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen You're talking about the Inventory History. That is separate from your Gift History.

Comment: @FAE Ah, yes it is. My bad...

Comment: I don't have `Steam Inventory` under the `View` menu....

Comment: @MatthewRead Oh wow. Totally forgot they changed the menus recently. Will update when I get home from work.

Comment: Hopefully something is still there, I did not have any luck with my search!

Comment: @MatthewRead That should do it! Sorry it took so long!

Comment: Perfect thanks!  I obviously do not use Steam regularly enough :P

Answer (score 2):

You can still see your Steam Store Gift Transactions. All you need to do is view your account (at the top right corner) and then click on Store Transactions. Under the main box that contains your purchases, there is the Gift Transaction box. You can see the date, the item, the method of acquisition and the price. However, it does not seem like you can see who you gifted the different items to.